# AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x10c49a668> ignored

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I'm trying to implement my coursera python project in flask environment. Also I'm using the https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky (branch 7a) to understand how the blueprints work. Now, I define 2 blueprints: main_blueprint & rpsls_blueprint. And get the following error after running application:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "..../app/__init__.py", line 29, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(rpsls_blueprint)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in register_blueprint
    if blueprint.name in self.blueprints:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'name'
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x10c49a668> ignored
```

Does someone know where the problem is?
Here is the related part of my `app/__init__.py` file:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .rpsls import rpsls as rpsls_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(rpsls_blueprint)

    return app
```

Here is my app/rpsls/rpsls.py file:

```
import random

class RpslsGame():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def name_to_number(self, name):
        if name == "rock":
            return 0
        elif name == "Spock":
            return 1
        elif name == "paper":
            return 2
        elif name == "lizard":
            return 3
        elif name == "scissors":
            return 4
        else:
            return name + " does not match any\
                            of the five correct input strings"

    def number_to_name(self, number):
        if number == 0:
            return "rock"
        elif number == 1:
            return "Spock"
        elif number == 2:
            return "paper"
        elif number == 3:
            return "lizard"
        elif number == 4:
            return "scissors"
        else:
            return str(number) + \
                "  is not in the correct range"

    def rpslsMethod(self, player_choice):
        result = ""
        result += "Player chooses " + str(player_choice) + "\n"
        player_number = self.name_to_number(player_choice)
        comp_number = random.randrange(0, 5)
        comp_choice = self.number_to_name(comp_number)
        result += "Computer chooses " + comp_choice + "\n"
        differene = (comp_number - player_number) % 5
        if (differene == 1 or differene == 2):
            result += "Computer wins\n"
        elif (differene == 3 or differene == 4):
            result += "Player wins\n"
        elif (differene == 0):
            result += "Try again, It's a tie\n"

        return result
```

My app/rpsls/**init**.py file:

```
from flask import Blueprint
rpsls = Blueprint('rpsls', __name__)
from . import views
```

Comment: `rpsls_blueprint` is a module, not a `Flask.Blueprint` object. Can you show us how the `rpsls` module is defined?

Comment: Please add more detail to the question, you can [edit] it.

Comment: I added my aap/rpsls/rpsls.py file above.

Comment: Right, that's a module; `app.rplsls.rpsls`. There is not even a flask Blueprint object in there. What did you expect that to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported the `rpls` module from the `rpls` package. That's a *module*, not a blueprint object.

You cannot register a module as a blueprint; you can only register [`flask.Blueprint()` instances](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Blueprint). You may want to read up on how [Flask Blueprints work](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/blueprints/).

You have both a `rpls` object in the `rpls` package, *and* a submodule. When the `app.rpls.rpls` module is imported, it **replaced** the `rpls` `Blueprint` instance in your `__init__.py` file; the namespaces are not separate.

Rename one or the other; the module or the `Blueprint` object.

Comment: I made it separately in app/rpsls/__init__.py file as above.

Comment: @Sarah: And did you name it `rpsls` *as well*? Did you import the `rpsls/rpsls` module at any point in the `__init__` or elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks :) I rename the app/rpsls/rpsls.py file and that fix the error!